# keyOutputText not work on soft keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

keyOutputText not work on soft keyboard.

```
>         <Key android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:keyOutputText=".net" android:keyLabel=".net"/>
>         <Key android:keyOutputText=".org" android:keyLabel=".org"/>
>         <Key android:keyOutputText=".gov" android:keyLabel=".gov"/>
>         <Key android:keyEdgeFlags="right" android:keyOutputText=".tw" android:keyLabel=".tw"/>
```

as above, but it does not write anything to the pressure button.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution..

> @Override
>       public void onText(CharSequence text) {
>
> ```
>     InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
>     ic.commitText(text, 0);
>
>
> }
> ```

Comment: thanks it works         heare is my work  " <Key android:codes="-105" android:keyOutputText="CC" android:keyLabel="CC" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>"